# How to solve @aws-crypto library compilation errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I'm working on a ReactJS project and I developed a strings encryption/decryption helper which makes use of the AWS KMS crypto library.

I haven't been able to compile the project for errors on the AWS library itself. I have the following error when using the `@aws-crypto/client-browser` module:

```
./node_modules/@aws-crypto/kms-keyring/build/module/src/kms_mrk_keyring.js 11:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   //# interface.md#interface)
|   extends BaseKeyring {
>     keyId;
|     client;
|     grantTokens; //= compliance/framework/aws-kms/aws-kms-mrk-aware-symmetric-keyring.txt#2.6
```

Node version 14.18

Package.json relevant blocks:

```
@aws-crypto/client-browser: ^3.1.0
```

tsconfig.json relevant info:

```
"target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
"jsx": "react-jsx"
```

Comment: Curious to learn more about what your app does and why do you use an aws package when you probably can use the web crypto api directly?

Comment: Because we use that library in the be also

Answer (score 0):

I solved it downgrading the `@aws-crypto/client-browser` version to `2.4.0`

`$ npm install @aws-crypto/client-browser@2.4.0`